Can lightning destroy 1 meter of concrete and steel with ease?
There is a character in my story who is a cyborg and as such they have decided to incorporate an electro laser into their body which has the same voltage and amperage as normal lightning due. An electrolaser uses a high power pulsed laser to create a plasma channel that can than conduct electricity and direct it at any place you desire. The laser is capable of piercing most materials with ease using a pulsed laser beam. There is also a villain that is a walking skyscraper. This character needs to destroy or at least cause the skyscraper to collapse. What are some ways they can use their lightning projection to destroy this building?

The skyscraper is about the size and weight of the average skyscraper.
The lightning still possesses the properties of normal lightning such as shockwaves that can shatter concrete and glass in a 1 meter radius with ease, heat 5 times hotter than the surface of the sun, and intense brightness.
The character is allowed to target weak points of the skyscraper
The character is able to sustain the lightning for a somewhat long time
To clarify this character should be capable of destroying 1 meter of concrete/pure steel in a relatively short amount of time.
Lastly, this character is able to aim lightning at places using the electrolaser. This allows them to not hit lightning rods and grounding routes and aim for more crucial weak points.


What is an electrolaser?

The constraint on having the building collapse/destroyed after 1Min is a tough call. What is the reason for this constraint? What if this requirement turns out to show that the lightning is not capable of destroying a building within 60secs. Also could you clarify if you mean "destroy=collapse" or what level of destruction are you seeking?

I suspect that your question will be closed in a few hours (because principles). Afterwards nobody will care about the question anymore. So, if this happens, I suggest to change your question into something more concrete and narrow scoped, like: "Is sustained lightning (from a weapon) capable of destroying/cutting a T-beam of pure steel into two halves? (Alternatively: A column of conrete with iron bars of the diameter of 1 meter) This way you avoid the "your question is too plot-specific" trap. You need to reason from the answers if this would allow the destruction. Be indirect.

There is a huge difference between a laser and lightning. Lasers are coherent light and cause heat. Lightning is an electrostatic discharge and it's complicated. But it's not light (although it gives off light) and it's not heat (although it can cause things to burn). The two "destroy" things in very different ways - but perhaps the biggest problem is that from a science perspective you can't arbitrarily direct an electrostatic discharge (you can't control where it goes), but you can control a laser. So, -1 for a confusing Q, but I'll retract if you [edit] it to clean it up. Thanks.

I'm also skeptical of the assertion of "properties of normal lightning".  I've seen lightning strikes that leave a scorch mark and nothing else, or strikes that explode a tree by boiling all the water inside it at once.  Not all lightning is created equal and there is no SI unit of lightning.

We need more information.  Real world skyscrapers vary greatly in size, don't walk and are held upright by their foundations.  How big is this skyscraper, how big are the magical(?) legs(?) that it is walking around on and how many legs(?) need to be destroyed in order to make the structure collapse?  Also, "a somewhat long time" and "a relatively short amount of time" could each mean anything from milliseconds to days - quantities, please.  Finally, note that your title question is self-answered by your 4th dot point - suggest editing the title.

It depends on where they use the lightning attack. For example if they shoot a lightning blast at glass than it will shatter but there will be only cosmetic effects to the building. However if they shot it at a pillar thay supports the building than there might be serious damage.
Another way for them to do a large amount of damage would be to start fires which lightning can easily do. They would simply need to aim inside the building and allow lightning to start a fire which would cause the building to eventually collapse.
The last thing that I will mention is the shockwave produced by lightning. It has been found that thunder produced by lightning is capable of shattering glass and concrete in a few meters as you mentioned. However the extent of this blast wave is comparable to a concussion grenade due to the fact that almost everything in a meter radius will be destroyed due to the large amount of sound.
Lastly, you mentioned that the lightning can be held in a place for a long time which means that heat and sound will both increase to devastating effect as time goes on.
Tldr: Your character should aim for pillars that support the skyscraper. Than start fires to weaken the overall defenses and lastly use the shockwave of lightning to shatter any pillars and windows.
BTW assuming the the shockwave of lightning is average or 279 psi from 2 centimeters/219.6 decibles than that means that the lightning attacks of your character should be able to shatter glass from 11 meters assuming 164 decibles is enough to shatter glass from sound alone. (If I'm wrong somebody correct me on this also I know this is wrong to do but why doesn't lightning shatter glass and concrete, launch a person around, or bend lightning rods when it strikes them?) Source https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6474511/
